# "On y trouve de tout"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, partitif

I heard this said by a native speaker, translated in subtitles as "We can find anything there." (With reference to shopping in Reims.)

I have not seen *trouver de qch* before. I would have thought this sentence should have been *On y tout trouve.* If that is wrong, why is it wrong? When should *trouve* be followed by *de*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Trouver* is transitive with a direct object. « Trouver de » is not a construction in itself, however *de* is commonly used as a partitive article after some verbs. In “trouver de l'argent”, *de l'argent* (some money) is a *direct* complement built with the partitive article.

*Tout* is a pronoun which like a few other pronouns (*ce*, *ceci*, *cela*, *ça*, *quelque chose*, *rien*, others?) can be used with a partitive article. This explains the use of *de tout* (a bit of everything) in your sentence.

The meaning of “de tout” is very close to “toutes sortes de choses” (all sorts of things, [as mentioned by BBBreiz](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18603/79)). Without the partitive, as in “On y trouve tout”, the meaning would be plainly and simply “everything”.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is wrong. You need to conjugate the verb:

*On trouve tout*

When talking about a place (like Reims), it is referenced by the "y":

*On y trouve tout*

"De tout" is used to say that you find "of everything" or "of all", not "everything" per se. So we add the "de". Otherwise, it would imply that you can *literally* find everything there.

Other example:

*Il est capable de tout (faire).* (He is capable of anything)

*Loin de tout* (Far away (from everything))

*De tout mon coeur* (with all my heart)

Comment: You may also say "On y trouve des produits laitiers", "On y trouve des vetements de luxe", for the structure "trouver de"

Comment: These "other examples" do not use the same kind of construction as in the original sentence. All these *de* are prepositions.

Comment: *Trouver* was a typo in my sentence, I fixed it, FYI. Indeed meant to write *trouve*.

Answer (score 1):

You might also say:
**"On peut y trouver de tout"** 
("*de tout*" means "*all sorts of things*" meanwhile "*tout*" means "*everything*".

Comment: I'm sorry, not conjugating the verb was just *une faute d'inattention.* I fixed it. Maybe update your answer to reflect that?

Comment: *All sorts of things* is a very good equivalent in terms of meaning indeed.

Answer (score 0):

"On y trouve de tout"

Is a common oral use in France.
To understand *de* like the *de* following an indirect transitive verb is a mistake.

Let me give you some examples :

> Au supermarché, on trouve :
>   des fruits,
>   des yaourts,
>   **du** lait,
>   **de** la viande
>   et enfin, des caissières souriantes

*de* is not related to the verb *trouver* construction, but to the property of the complement to be countable or not. *fruits*, *yaourts*, *caissières* are countable, in this case don't use *de*. *lait*, *viande* are not countable, then use *de* (like *some* in english : *some milk*, *some meat*)

Then how about *anything*? Is *anything* countable or not? That's a good question. French grammar says no, that's why we say *de tout*.